# How can I validate a form if any one input field has filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have 10 input fields and 2 select boxes in a JSP form. I need to validate that form, if any one input field is filled I need to show an alert message.

Is there any possible way to validate this in jQuery?

Comment: `jQueryObj.filter(function(){ this.value!=''; }).length`

Comment: Can you explain your requirement a bit more? You want to alert a message if one of 10 input fields is filled with text?

Comment: yes,out of 10 input fields if any one text field is filled in the form i need to through an alert

Comment: @Kayathiri Please don't use code formatting (backticks, `\``) for anything other than code. JSP and jQuery are names, not code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var varFilledTextboxCount = $("input[type='text']").filter(function () { 
                                  return this.value != ''; 
                            }).length;
if (varFilledTextboxCount > 0)
{
   alert("Any textbox is filled");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following plugin to validate any form! Please go through the documentation and get an idea on how to implement it. If you face any problem, please ask.

[jQuery Form Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple code of jquery for this.

```
var filledCount = 0;
var inputLength = $('form').find('input').length;
var i;
for(i=0;i<inputLength;i++){
  if($(this).val()!=0){
    filledCount = filledCount + 1;
  };
  if(filledCount>0){
    alert('something');
    break;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css class **`valueFilled`** while user change the input or select fields. Then check whether the **`valueFilled length`** is available or not. If it is available then you can show the alert box.

```
jQuery('form').on("change", "input, select", function () {
   if('' != jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val())){
       jQuery(this).addClass('valueFilled');
    }
});
```

Then check the valueFilled class length

```
if(jQuery('.valueFilled').length){
  // Show message here
}
```